# tkinter GUI hangs when encrypting large file

Tags: python, encryption, tkinter, freeze

Once the user imports a text file, it is then displayed on scrolledtext. Then it is encrypted using a translator and displayed on another scrolledtext like so:

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter.ttk import * 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *

letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

encryption_code = 'LFWOAYUISVZMNXPBDCRJTQEGHK'

letters += letters.lower() 
encryption_code += encryption_code.lower()

enc = dict(zip(letters,encryption_code))

window = tkinter.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(window)
style.configure("BW.TLabel")

import_frame = tkinter.Frame(window)

def import_txt():
    global import_list    
    file_name = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")]) 

    import_list = [] 

    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        import_list = f.readlines() 
        encrypttxt.pack()
    f.close() 

def encrypt_txt():
    global letters
    global encryption_code
    global import_list
    global translated
    pre = "".join(import_list)
    translated = "".join([i.translate(str.maketrans(letters, encryption_code)) for i in import_list]) 
    display_txt.insert('insert', translated) 
    precrypt.insert('insert', pre)
    display_txt.pack(side=RIGHT)
    precrypt.pack(side=LEFT)

display_txt = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(import_frame)
encrypttxt = ttk.Button(import_frame, text="Encrypt", command=encrypt_txt)
precrypt = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(import_frame)
start = ttk.Button(window, text="START", command=import_txt)
start.pack()
import_frame.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

My problem is that the program hangs when a large file is imported and encrypted. The larger the file, the longer it hangs.

Comment: it is natural in all GUI. use `threads`

Comment: Expanding a bit on @furas comment, the normal way to do this is to perform the encryption/decryption in a separate thread of execution, have the encryption thread send progress updates to the GUI thread, and the GUI thread reports the progress to the user via something like a progress bar or a %done counter.

Comment: So, I can use a progress bar to display how long it will take to encrypt then `pack()` the `scrolledtext` once it is done?